# Doc2vec predictions - do we average the words or what is the paragraph ID for a new paragraph?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, word-embedding, doc2vec

I understand that you treat the paragraph ID as a new word in doc2vec (DM approach, left on the figure) during training. The training output is the context word. After a model is trained, suppose I want to get 1 embedding given a new document.

Do I feed each word to the network and then average it to get the embedding? Or is there another way?

I can feed this to gensim, but I am trying to understand how it works.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

During model bulk training, the candidate doc-vector is gradually nudged to be better at predicting the text's words, just like word-vector training. So at the end of training, you have doc-vectors for all the identifiers you provided alongside the texts.

You can access these from a `gensim` `Doc2Vec` model via doct-style indexed lookup of the identifier (called 'doctag' in `gensim') you provided during training:`model.docvecs[tag]`

Post-training, to get the doc-vector for a new text, an inference process is used. The model is held frozen, and a new random candidate vector (just like those that started bulk training for training texts) is formed for the text. Then it's incrementally nudged, in a manner fully analogous to training, to be better at predicting the words – but only this one new candidate vector is changed. (All model internal weights stay the same.)

You can calculate such new vectors via the `infer_vector()` method, which takes a list-of-word-tokens that should have been preprocessed just like the texts provided during training: `model.infer_vector(words)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think using the above methods that freezes the model, only random new paragraph vectors and retraining should be more effective, but I see a statement that simply using the average of all word vectors in a sentence is more effective in some cases.